# What would be the best Magento solution for simple quote requests

Tags: magento

What I want to do is this. Nothing on my site is for direct sale so all of te cart functionality is mostly useless. What I would like to do instead is add products to the cart(a quote cart) and then instead of buying the product they simple submit the "order" for quotation. I've done a lot of research and it seems that many of the plugins out there are overkill. I don't need to manage these quotes on the backend or even correspond with the customer through Magento. In fact I believe these quotes are going to end up in Zoho CRM or simply be handled via email. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: you can set prices to all your products to 0 and define a "fake payment" method so customer can bypass the payment step and go further.

Comment: I've heard that might be an option but I'm not completely sure how to implement it. What would this 'fake' payment method entail. At some point they would need to submit the request containing all of the products in their cart.

Comment: by "fake payment method", I talk of a payment method that will record an order even without payment. For instance, on my website, I use a "prepaid" method which completes order but isnt requiring any kind of transaction. The transaction is made outside of our website and once we ve got it, we send the product. So for your need, it can be good as you will still have your quote request processed anyway.

Comment: Tried adding a new payment method following thise tutorial. http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/adding-new-payment-module-in-magento/ . Problem is it is still a standard purchase page and the payment method isn't available to my store but the default config. I think what I would ideally want to happen is instead of a "Proceed to Cart" button on the cart page it goes to a 'checkout' page that is only requesting contact info.

Comment: you can do a thing like that to bypass cart http://www.magecorner.com/bypass-cart-and-go-to-checkout/

Comment: This one i found perfect https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html